# PHP date function not working as expected

Tags: php, date

I am using this echo(date("Y",'2009-10-01')); to extract the year but it only gives me the incorrect year 1970 or 1969!

What am i doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Does nobody read the manual anymore?  http://php.net/manual/en/index.php

Comment: based on questions like this, I would say infrequently and poorly.

Answer (score 5):

change to

```
echo(date("Y",strtotime('2009-10-01')));
```

and try again

Comment: Thanks figured it out last week.